# How To Read in Strings that only Contain Alphabet letters with fscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have been struggling to figure out the fscanf formatting.  I just want to read in a file of words delimited by spaces.  And I want to discard any strings that contain non-alphabetic characters.

```
char temp_text[100];
while(fscanf(fcorpus, "%101[a-zA-Z]s", temp_text) == 1) {
  printf("%s\n", temp_text);
}
```

I've tried the above code both with and without the 's'.  I read in another stackoverflow thread that the s when used like that will be interpreted as a literal 's' and not as a string.  Either way - when I include the s and when I do not include the s - I can only get the first word from the file I am reading through to print out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%[` scan specifier does not skip leading spaces. Either add a space before it or at the end in place of your `s`. Also you have your 100 and 101 backwards and thus a serious buffer overflow bug.

Comment: Thanks on both corrections!  I changed the width parameter and added a space after the ']' in place of the s and everything is now working smoothly :-)  As a more general question, is it best to only use type specifiers when they serve the exact purpose you want?  Do you ever find yourself using type specifiers in combination with modifiers?

Comment: I find myself rarely using the `scanf` family of functions. Every time I try to use them, I run into a slight deviation from the behavior I'm trying to get that's either difficult or impossible to work around. Usually `fgets` or even `fgetc` ends up being easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

The s isn't needed.

**Here are a few things to try:**

Print out the return value from fscanf, and make sure it is 1.

Make sure that the fscanf is consuming the whitespace by using fgetc to get the next character and printing it out.

Comment: Ah.  You helped me spot what R. was hitting on, the next space wasn't being read.  Thanks!